# SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed. Even after i imported the certificate

Tags: java, ssl, jvm, ssl-certificate, keytool

I am trying to get data from a site through an API. I received the following error.

`The exception occurred is : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I have downloaded the certificate (Base64 encoded .cer format) and added it following the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ). When i run this on a windows system, the error is getting resolved. But when i follow the same solution in a CENT OS system, the error still persists.

**Why is the certificate not being recognized in CENT OS. Do I have to import the certificate differently for different OS systems.**

Here's the full error log.

```
11:31:42 ERROR CaseManagementController {? ?} - The exception occurred is : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:557)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at com.gavs.gavel.controllers.CaseManagementController$$anonfun$getMEServiceDeskPlusPriorityList$1.apply(CaseManagementController.scala:2126)
    at com.gavs.gavel.controllers.CaseManagementController$$anonfun$getMEServiceDeskPlusPriorityList$1.apply(CaseManagementController.scala:2103)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Function1.scala:52)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilderImpl.invokeBlock(Action.scala:482)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilderImpl.invokeBlock(Action.scala:480)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$2.apply(Action.scala:419)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:96)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:89)
    at play.api.libs.streams.StrictAccumulator$$anonfun$mapFuture$2$$anonfun$1.apply(Accumulator.scala:174)
    at play.api.libs.streams.StrictAccumulator$$anonfun$mapFuture$2$$anonfun$1.apply(Accumulator.scala:174)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at play.api.libs.streams.StrictAccumulator$$anonfun$mapFuture$2.apply(Accumulator.scala:174)
    at play.api.libs.streams.StrictAccumulator$$anonfun$mapFuture$2.apply(Accumulator.scala:170)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Function1.scala:52)
    at play.api.libs.streams.StrictAccumulator.run(Accumulator.scala:207)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$15.apply(AkkaHttpServer.scala:337)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$15.apply(AkkaHttpServer.scala:335)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.akka$http$scaladsl$util$FastFuture$$strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:41)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$$anonfun$transformWith$extension1$1.apply(FastFuture.scala:51)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$$anonfun$transformWith$extension1$1.apply(FastFuture.scala:50)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:43)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
        ... 50 more

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
        ... 56 more
```

When i try **'curl'** command on the site I'm trying to access, i get the following:

```
    curl: (60) Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Answer (score -1):

You need also to add the **entire chain** of root certificates from your CA. You can check [this page](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO16297.html) for more info.

> A certificate chain is an ordered list of certificates, containing an
>   SSL Certificate and Certificate Authority (CA) Certificates, that
>   enable the receiver to verify that the sender and all CA's are
>   trustworthy. The chain or path begins with the SSL certificate, and
>   each certificate in the chain is signed by the entity identified by
>   the next certificate in the chain.
>
> Any certificate that sits between the SSL Certificate and the Root
>   Certificate is called a chain or Intermediate Certificate. The
>   Intermediate Certificate is the signer/issuer of the SSL  Certificate.
>   The Root CA Certificate is the signer/issuer of the Intermediate
>   Certificate. If the Intermediate Certificate is not installed on the
>   server (where the SSL certificate is installed) it may prevent some
>   browsers, mobile devices, applications, etc. from trusting the SSL
>   certificate. In order to make the SSL certificate compatible with all
>   clients, it is necessary that the Intermediate Certificate be
>   installed.
>
> The chain terminates with a Root CA Certificate. The Root CA
>   Certificate is always signed by the CA itself. The signatures of all
>   certificates in the chain must be verified up to the Root CA
>   Certificate.

Comment: If intermediate certs are the issue, why does it work on my windows system